# How to use groovy to populate an env variable in a declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am struggling to populate an environment variable in a Jenkinsfile using groovy

The code below fails:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    PACKAGE_NAME = JOB_NAME.tokenize('/')[1]
  }
{
```

with the following error:

> Environment variable values can only be joined together with ‘+’s

What am I doing wrong? Sorry if the question is basic, I am just starting with both groovy and pipelines.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Declarative pipeline is pretty strict about the values you can assign to environment variables. For instance, if you try to set `PACKAGE_NAME` to `JOB_NAME` you will get following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 5: Environment variable values must either be single quoted, double quoted, or function calls. @ line 5, column 24.
       PACKAGE_NAME = JOB_NAME
```

To avoid getting errors and set `PACKAGE_NAME` env variable as expected you can put it into double quotes and evaluate expression inside the GString:

```
environment {
    PACKAGE_NAME = "${JOB_NAME.tokenize('/')[1]}"
}
```

Comment: I keep running into this, and it's mostly right, except that if your env var comes out as `null`, your custom variable will be a _string_ with content "null", and not actually a null object. As far as I can tell, i have to also specifically check if the string content is "null".

Comment: This means I cannot use BOOLEAN environment variables. true and false should be "true" and "false"...